# Not getting user's Facebook Profile picture using SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I am using **Facebook SDK** for facebook login.I am fetching user's name and profile picture.Everything was working fine since yesterday but when I try to Log In today, I can not get profile picture but can get Name only.
What should be problem?
Any solution?
Any help or advice are appreciated.
This URL I am using to get profile picture :

```
ProfilePic_URL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+e.mProfile.Id+"/picture?type=large";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just solved my problem by changing http to https in URL.So simple..

Answer (score 1):

I think Your URL is changed.
It may be change in your mProfile.id
Debug that and Observe which id is get